# Subgroups of $S_{n}$

Tags: group-theory

There's the theorem that states that every finite group $G$ of order $n$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_{n}$. My question is, "How do we find that subgroup?"

Comment: This is generally a very hard problem It's not even known what the smallest $n$ is, generally. Even if you want just the one given to you by the proof of the theorem you have to know the entire Cayley table for the group.

Comment: And as you can see from the answers, you CANNOT easily find the subgroup. All of them are fine as abstract embeddings, but note that you need to find a numbering for your group and see EXACTLY how each element of the group multiplies EVERY OTHER ELEMENT to get the description. Hence it is very unsatisfying and incredibly difficult to do, regardless of the general theory.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the morphism $\theta : g\in G \mapsto (h\in G\mapsto g.h\in G)\in \mathrm{Bij}(G)\cong S_{|G|}$. It is an injective map (if $g\in \mathrm{Ker}(\theta)$, then $g.e=e$ so $g=e$), so $G$ is isomorphic to his image which is a subgroup of $S_{|G|}$.

Comment: Three people come head in head with the answer. Bravo!

Answer (score 3):

The theorem is called [Cayley's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_theorem).

The proof is constructive: Number the elements of the group $g_1,\dots,g_n$ and consider the map $\phi : G \to S_n$ given by $\phi(g)(i)=j$, where $gg_i=g_j$. This map is an injective homomorphism and its image is a subgroup of $S_n$ that is isomorphic to $G$. You can list this subgroup explicitly by using the multiplication table of $G$.

Answer (score 2):

Easy: give a name to the elements of $G$, e.g., $G=\{g_1,\ldots,g_n\}$; then you have the group monomorphism:

$$\Phi:G\longrightarrow S_n:x\longmapsto\sigma_x$$
where $g_{\sigma_x(k)}=xg_k$.