# Subgroups of Sufficiently Large Symmetric Groups / Cayley's Theorem explanation

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

Here's the question: **is every finite group a subgroup of a symmetric group of sufficiently large order?** More specifically, if a group $G$ has order $n$, then is it true that $G \le S_{n}$?

For instance, both groups of order $4$ can be found in $S_4$. $\{(1), (1 2 3 4), (1 3)(2 4), (1 4 3 2)\} \cong C_4$ and $\{(1), (1 2), (3 4), (1 2)(3 4)\} \cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$. Also, in general, $C_n, A_n, D_{2n}, S_n \le S_n$.

After a short investigation, I was unable to find a subgroup in $S_4$ that was congruent to $Q$, the unit quaternions, but I would be quite surprised if $Q \not\le S_8$.

---

Okay, the answer is "yes", and this is known as [Cayley's Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CayleysGroupTheorem.html). However, the link points to a proof-less page and the proofs given on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_theorem) aren't very clear, so I would really, really appreciate a clear, intuitive, and conceptual proof of Cayley's Theorem.

Comment: What is the action of each element of $Q$ on the elements of $Q$.  I.e., how does "multiplication on the left by the element $x$" permute the elements of $Q$ as you iterate $x$ through $Q$?  This should suggest to you that the multiplication table of a group can be embedded in permutations of the elements of the group...

Comment: [Cayley's Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CayleysGroupTheorem.html).

Comment: @David: Cayley's Theorem is exactly what I was suspecting.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/854561/589.

Comment: Please explain why the proofs at Wikipedia do not work for you.

Comment: @lhf: Basically, too much jargon and not enough intuition. I am new to the area of groups so I haven't gotten used to all the jargon. mesel's answer is pretty much exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intuation is that $$gG=G$$ for any $g\in G$ which means that every $g$ of permutes the elements of $G$. Surprisingly the corresponding permutations elements constitute a subgroup of $S_G$ which is isomorphic to $G$.

---

If $G$ is simple, $G$ can be embeded into $A_n$ where $n$ is the smallest index of nontrivial subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Ah! That's just the sort of intuition I was looking for! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

In any group $G$, any element $g \in G$ defines a function from $G$ to itself denoted $L_g : G \to G$, called "left multiplication":
$$L_g(h) = gh
$$
The group axioms show that this function is injective
$$L_g(h) = L_g(h') \iff gh = gh' \iff h=h'
$$ 
and that it is onto
$$L_g(g^{-1} h) = g g^{-1} h = h
$$
Therefore the formula $g \mapsto L_g$ defines a function $G \mapsto Sym(G)$, where $Sym(G)$ denotes the "symmetric group" of the set $G$, namely the group of self-bijections of $G$. The group axioms also show that the function $g \mapsto L_g$ is a homomorphism
$$L_{g_1} \circ L_{g_2} (h) = g_1(g_2(h)) = (g_1 g_2)(h) = L_{g_1 g_2}(h)
$$
and that it is injective
$$L_g(h)=h \iff gh=h \iff g=Id
$$
Therefore, $G$ embeds in $Sym(G)$ which is isomorphic to $S_{|G|}$; that isomorphism is obtained by enumerating the elements of $G$.

Answer (score 1):

Yup.  $G$ is always a subgroup of $S_{|G|}$.

On a related note, the question of the *smallest* $n$ such that $G\leq S_n$ is, in general, not known.